# I am wanting to enter a new row if there is only 1 row for a LaborCostId. If there are two rows, then ignore

Tags: sql-server, count, rows

I have a table with several columns as shown below. I am wanting to write an `UPDATE` statement to schedule to only insert a new row if a `LaborCostID` only appears once. This new row will contain the same `LaborCostID` as the single row items. If a `LaborCostID` has two rows, I want to ignore it. So for the example below, I need to insert a new row with (LaborCostID = 181614, CostCode = 'Regular Benefits', Cost = 11.946)

- Column Name - LaborCostID  with Values (181614, 181615, 181615, 181616, 181616)
- Column Name - CostCode with Values (Regular, Overtime, Overtime Benefits, Regular, Regular Benefits)
  Benefits)
- Column Name - Cost with Values (0.000000, 15.000000, 3.795000, 0.000000, 11.946000)

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: Sorry, yes I was using the incorrect term. I knew what I needed, just incorrect term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I figured out a Where statement that helped me get it.
select *
from azteca.LABORCOSTACTDETAIL t1
where LABORCOSTID IN (Select *
From (Select LABORCOSTID
From azteca.LABORCOSTACTDETAIL
Group By LABORCOSTID
Having Count(azteca.LABORCOSTACTDETAIL.LABORCOSTID) = 1)
as a);

Comment: A window function `COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` will be more performant